Testing PrimeReact SplitButton with RTL and Jest: Displaying Items on Click
I’m working with the PrimeReact SplitButton component, and I want to write tests to ensure that it displays the additional options correctly when clicked. Specifically, I’d like to verify that the dropdown menu opens and shows the expected items.
Here’s how I’m using the SplitButton in my application:
import { SplitButton } from "primereact/splitbutton";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const MenuBtn = () => {
  const items = [
    {
      label: "Item 1",
      command: () => {
        router.push({
          pathname: "/path/to",
          query: {
            ...router.query,
          },
        });
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Item 2",
      command: () => {
        router.push({
          pathname: "/path/to",
          query: {
            ...router.query,
          },
        });
      },
    },
  ];
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
        <SplitButton
          buttonClassName="bgGreen"
          menuButtonClassName="bgGreen"
          label="Menu"
          onClick={() => {}}
          model={items}
          id="menu-btn"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MenuBtn

;
I’ve set up my test environment with RTL and Jest, but I’m unsure how to simulate the button click and check if the menu items are displayed. Here’s a snippet of my test so far:
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MenuBtn from './btn/MenuBtn';

test('SplitButton displays items when clicked', () => {
  render(<MenuBtn />);
  const btn = await screen.findByText('Menu');
  expect(btn).toBeInTheDocument();
  fireEvent.click(btn);
  screen.getByText('Item 1');
  screen.getByText('Item 2');
});


